# use javascript variable in html script

Tags: javascript, html

I have an AJAX function in my JavaScript like so

```
function getWeather(countryName) {
    const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];

    let dateObj = new Date();
    let month = monthNames[dateObj.getUTCMonth()];
    let day = dateObj.getUTCDate() - 1;
    let year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

    let newDate = `${month} ${day}, ${year}`;
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/geojson/countryBorders.geo.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            
        },
        success: function(result) {
.... etc
```

Within my HTML modal for displaying the weather per country, I would like to include things such as the date.

Is there any way to use the Javascript variable `newDate` in the HTML script?

something like ....?

```
 <div class="modal-body">
          <h6 id="capitalCity" class="modal-sub-header"></h6>
          <hr>
          <ul class="dem">
              <p class="date" id="newDate"></p>
```

Comment: Do you want to insert the value of the `newDate` variable inside the html?

Comment: @FrancoA.Torres yes please

Comment: Try the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaboration on Franco A. Torreses answer
this will be your javascript

```js
function getWeather(countryName) {
    const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];

    let dateObj = new Date();
    let month = monthNames[dateObj.getUTCMonth()];
    let day = dateObj.getUTCDate() - 1;
    let year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

    let newDate = `${month} ${day}, ${year}`;
    document.getElementById('newData').textContent = newDate
```

And your HTML will stay the same.
document.getElementById('newData') grabs the element from DOM and .textContent sets it's text to whatever is after =. This is also superior to using .innerHTML as .innerHTML it allows for injections.

If you are after using variables in HTML, you could take a look into either frontent frameworks such as React, VueJS, Angular that allow just using {variable} or some other backend languages such as PHP.

**Edit**

Regarding innerHTML. As was stated in comments by @tacoshy "innerHTML poses a security issue as it is open for XSS injections if the injected code isn't validated" This is because textContent does not let you insert HTML elements (opposed to .innerHTML), but you don't have to worry about that if your application does not have any user input. Also it's more performant as it does not require DOM-reparse.

Comment: `textContent` is not superior because `innerHTML` allows for injections. What you mean is that `innerHTML` poses a security issue as it is open for XSS injections if the injected code isn't validated (validate the code and you are fine). The reason why `textContent` is more efficient is, that `innerHTML` needs the DOM to re-parse which takes more time. As such it is more efficient as long as you only try to insert a text (not superior as it has its limitations compared to `innerHTML`)

Comment: @tacoshy You are absolutely right, I just did not want to confuse him with paragraph of regarding something that was not exactly asked. I will refer to your comment in the post.

Comment: Of course, you can quote me. IMHO there is always a place to review code and to change parts of it to be more efficient. There is also enough space to teach the OP those other methods and explain to him why his knowledge is outdated or inefficient. Learning is the purpose of SO after all.

Answer (score 1):

To insert a value inside a DOM element:

```
document.getElementById('newData').textContent = 'the value'
```

The document method `getElementById` retrieves the DOM element by its id, which in this case is `newData`. The DOM element method `textContent` changes the DOM element's text.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dateOptions = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat( 'en-US', dateOptions ).format;

document.getElementById('newData').textContent = dateFormatter( new Date() );

// Result = October 28, 2022
```

You can use the browser native function `Intl.DateTimeFormat` to format your date as needed without having to run lots of logic or using 3rd party code.

- [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)
- [Intl.DateTimeFormat Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat#using_options)